# Вложенные fetch запросы js nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

Мне нужно реализовать функцию с использованием вложенных fetch запросов. Получаю следующие ошибки
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found);
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

```
async function getCart() {
    fetch(base_api_path + '/cart/getAllOrders', {method: 'GET'})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        res.forEach(income => {
              .....
            fetch(base_api_path+'/cart/getItems',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        id: income.itemId
                       
                    }
                )
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
            res.forEach(intel => {
                .....
               })
             })
            })
   
}
```

Подскажите, можно ли вообще использовать fetch внутри fetch, и в чем моя ошибка?

```
exports.getAllOrders = async function (req, res) {
if(req.user){
const allOrders = await Orders.findAll({ where: { userId: req.user.id } })
res.send(JSON.stringify(allOrders)) }
}

exports.getItems = async function (req, res) {
    const allItems = await Items.findAll({ where: { id: req.body.id } })
    res.send(JSON.stringify(allItems));
}
```

Comment: ошибка в том, что какой-то из запросов отвечает 404 статусом, и в теле возвращает не json, а html. Из-за этого, какой-то из вызовов `res.json()` падает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть async. Ещё вижу await. Значит знакомы с этим понятием. Тогда совсем не ясно зачем использовать promise hell и callback hell, от которых async await вполне себе избавляет.

У вас небольшой хаос. Вы и используете async/await, который работает с промисами и одновременно используете then. Зачем - непонятно.

Вот простой случай работы с `fetch`:

```
async function getSmth() {
    const response = await fetch('/getSmth');
    const data = await response.json();            
}
```

Соответственно чтобы сделать второй `fetch`, его надо написать ниже.

(код взят из https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await)

```
async function getSmth() {
    // запрашиваем JSON с данными пользователя
    let response = await fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json');
    let user = await response.json();
    
    // запрашиваем информацию об этом пользователе из github
    let githubResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}`);
    let githubUser = await githubResponse.json();
}
```

Видите как просто и легко работать с асинхронными запросами (даже с несколькими) и ответами?

---

По вопросу об ошибке:  какой-то из запросов отвечает не 200 статусом, и в теле возвращает не json, а что-то другое, сокрее всего html. Из-за этого, какой-то из вызовов `res.json()` падает.